# При выборе значения в combobox курсор перемещается в конец строки

Tags: asp.net, javascript, extjs, css

У ext.net есть контрол combobox, который по сути является input type="text". При выборе некоторые текстовки бывают достаточно длинными, чтобы вмещались полностью в инпут. При этом когда я выбираю другой элемента, нажимая на кнопку, из списка комбобокса, курсор переходит из начала строки в конец. 
Есть ли какой-нибудь способ (любой - css, javascript или стандартными средствами ext.net, extjs или asp.net) устранить сей негативный фактор?